# Notification was not showing full layout

Tags: android, custom-notification

I was working in android Custom Notifications, for that I designed Custom Layout. but when I got notification Some part of this layout was not showing. [please check the screen shot of Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSFt.png)

please some one suggest me how to use custom layouts for Notifications.how ever My code was like below.

my actual custom layout code was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notificationHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/startedVideoStreaming"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5dp"
        android:background="@color/silvercolor"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pauseId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="pause"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stopLiveId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="StopLive"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my android code was

```
 private void showForegroundNotification() {
        RemoteViews contentLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
        contentLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationHeader, getString(R.string.startedVideoStreaming));
        contentLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.pauseId, "Pause");
        contentLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.stopLiveId, "StopLive");

        final NotificationManager notifyManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Intent to call our activity from background.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification.
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContent(contentLayout)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 500)
                    .build();
        }

        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        notifyManager.notify(STREAMER_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

please some one help to get out of this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this current code, remove the following line from your code

```
.setContent(contentLayout)
```

add the line above when You set the flag

```
notification.bigContentView = contentLayout;
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

Comment: @Basha if this code helps u, kindly accept the answer. People will be benefited later. Thanks.